# Codeception skipps test method even if depend-upon test was passed

Tags: skip, codeception, depends

I looked into manual here:
http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage
and there is ability to set @depens annotation for method.

```
class InvoiceStatusCest
{
    public function testOne()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo()
    {
    }

}
```

But for my surprise my testTwo() *always* skips, even if testOne() if empty or passed...

i see in console

```
Running InvoiceStatusCest.testOne - Ok
 - Skipped
```

Answer (score 3):

I had issues with making a test depend on another test in another Cest. Using the just name of the test from the other Cest in the `@depends` annotation worked for me:

```
class InvoiceCest
{
    public function testCreate()
    {

    }
}

class InvoiceStatusCest
{
   /**
     * @depends testCreate
     */
    public function testChangeInvoiceStatus()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: MC, I see you. This works but how do I ensure the skipped test reruns?

Answer (score 2):

In your version of codeception dependencies are not handles very well, but you can accomplish what you want using this annotation instead:

```
class InvoiceStatusCest
{
    public function testOne()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @depends Codeception\TestCase\Cest::testOne
     */
    public function testTwo()
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Codeception has some seriously finicking annotation

For instance
this

```
/*
 * @depends testOne
 */
```

will NOT work but this

```
/**
 * @depends testOne
 */
```

will work

NOTE the single * versus the ** at the beginning.

Just spent 4 hours of my life discovering this...

Comment: /* comment */  vs. /** PHPDoc block comment */   The double asterisk denotes a PHPDoc comment, which is required.